# Setting focus after an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a user input page that should allow for speedy data entry. There is a barcode scanner attached to the computer that sends the code + chr(13) to the highlighted input field.

What I want to do is scan the barcode, search the database and when it finds the barcode, enter the data and move on to the next line.

The code works fine, and focus is being set to the new element. However, it looks like the Ajax-call is stealing the focus back to the calling element. How can I resolve this?

This is the full JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function newTableRow(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode !== 9) return;

    if ($(e.delegateTarget).parent().is(':last-child')) {
      addTableRow();
    }
  }

  function addTableRow() {
    $('#tblData > tbody tr:last').after(`<tr>
                            <td><input type=\"text\" size=\"20\" name=\"ean\" /></td>
                            <td><input type=\"text\" size=\"20\" name=\"key\" /></td>
                            <td><input type=\"text\" size=\"40\" name=\"title\" /></td>
                        </tr>`);

    // Re-bind the events to the new tablerow
    $('#tblData > tbody tr td:last').on('keydown', 'input', null, addTableRow);
    $('#tblData > tbody tr td').on('keydown', 'input', null, searchDB);
    // Set focus to first element for keyboard input
    $('#tblData > tbody tr:last td:first').focus();
  }

  function searchDB(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode !== 13) return;

    var value = $(e.target).val();
    var tablerow = $(e.target).closest('tr');
    var addrow = false;

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "searcharticles.php",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {
          search_param: value
        }
      })
      .done(function(xml) {
        var id = 0;

        $(xml).find('artikel').each(function() {
          id = $(this).find('id').text();
          if (id == -1) {
            tablerow.find('td input:eq(2)').val('Not found');
          } else {
            tablerow.find('td input:eq(1)').val($(this).find('key').text());
            tablerow.find('td input:eq(2)').val($(this).find('title').text());
            addrow = true;
          }
        });
      })
      .fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      })
      .always(function() {
        if (addrow && $(e.delegateTarget).parent().is(':last-child')) {
          addTableRow();
        }
      });
  }

  $('#tblData > tbody tr td:last').on('keydown', 'input', null, newTableRow);
  $('#tblData > tbody tr td').on('keydown', 'input', null, searchDB);

});
```

Comment: As long as `addTableRow` is called from the `always` handler, it should work, as `always` is called after `done`

Comment: It should be noted that you seem to be rebinding delegated event handlers on each function call, and probably end up having more than one event handler bound ?

Comment: Yes, that was my idea as well. In the debugger it gets called, sets focus and then through the inner magic of JQuery focus is pulled away again.

Oops, that's an error on my end. It should only bind to the newly added row. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just place this at the end of the `.done()` callback instead of before the Ajax request.

```
// Set focus to first element for keyboard input
$('#tblData > tbody tr:last td:first').focus();
```

Ajax is asynchronous.

Since there is some DOM operation in `.done()` a couple ms after Ajax has sent, the `focus()` may be lost. Focussing an `input` to prepare the user for another action should be the last operation to be done.

I can't see any other reason for this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't really change anything. Is there a way to make a jsfiddle of an ajax request? Because I have the idea that the combination of ajax and adding an element is the cause of this

Comment: It think it is possible on [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) but I didn't use it much. Here is their [documentation](http://phpfiddle.org/deposit/documents.php).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure why this is an answer, but if I assign an ID to the first TD of the new table row and set focus to that, it works.

If I assign an ID to the table row and set focus to that ID and TD:First, it doesn't work. Something quirky going on there. I'm going to leave this question open in case someone can clarify, but this is a way to work around the issue.